# FLARtoolkit - is it possible to hide the webcam? (Action-Script 3)

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam, toolkit

at the moment I´m working at a project for my university where the user should be able to control a dynamic generated movie with printed markers and the webcam.
For this purpose, I thought it would be a nice idea to use the [FLARSquidderkit](http://rawkes.com/articles/tracking-multiple-augmented-reality-markers-flarmanager-and-papervision) (which provides multiple marker detection) based on the [FLARtoolkit](http://saqoo.sh/a/en/flartoolkit/start-up-guide) - but here is my problem: The webcam image is always in foreground and therefore hiding the generated movie.
Is there a way or function to bring the webcam image in background or make it invisible?

It would make my life so much easier if you have some ideas to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FLARSquidderkit or tested this, but judging from the link you provided and the code excerpts there, it looks like you could try this - not adding the webcam to the display list by removing or commenting out the `addChild` call where it says `/* Display webcam */` in `initFLAR`:

```
private function initFLAR():void {
    // ...

    /* Display webcam */
    //this.addChild(Sprite(fm.flarSource));
}
```

An alternative, if the `flarSource` needs to be on the display list for things to work, you could try and place it outside the visible stage, by setting its `x` and `y` properties to -1000 or such.

Comment: great point - its hidden in the FLARBaseApplication.as, in the init() function you can find the variable _flarBitmap were its easily possible to change all the attributes for stage properties and so forth... thank you very much :)